# how to keep my android phone always on display ,to anytime check my timings for bus app?

Tags: android

I have an old android phone which uses LCD screen.I often use an app to check bus timings before leaving home (on my new phone).I feel it would be helpful to make this app run on my old phone and keep the display always ON and running the bus app. Is there any developer option to set this up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the developer options there is "Stay awake", which will keep the device awake while it is charging. That would probably be your best and easiest way to accomplish this.

Comment: That's right but would work only when connected to a power source

Comment: @Chris623 If you're wanting to keep the display on all the time, you'll need a power source or it'll die. If you don't want that, then just setting the timeout to 30mins will probably work enough. Just wake it up once a day before heading out.